# Incorporating a company in the US. Does it improve or hinder the chances for B1 visa?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, mexico, russian-citizens

So, my previous application for the B1 visa was rejected a few years ago "for the lack of ties". Despite having a previous history of travel to the US and being financially well off. I'm retrying it soon, and what's changed since then is that I got permanent residency here in Mexico and a full time job for the couple last years - as opposed to my previous freelance work. Also, I want to start a company in the US for my personal projects, and I wonder if this would be considered a positive or negative factor?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148575/discussion-on-question-by-user626528-incorporating-a-company-in-the-us-does-it); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a company in the US would be a **negative** factor in getting a visitor visa. It gives you extra incentive to stay in the US, and indicates you intention to do more in the US than simply visit.

As jcaron says, immigration are looking for more ties *to your home country*, not more ties to the US.

Having residency in Mexico and a full time permanent job there would be positives.

Comment: Well, maybe. I'd better wait with opening the company or choose another country for that.

Comment: @user626528 waiting to open the company would only have a modest benefit, since once the visa is granted there is still the possibility of your ties to your place of residence being assessed every time you enter the US. (And for a Russian citizen the maximum validity of a B visa is three years, so you'll have to be reevaluated by the consulate fairly soon.) The B-1 visa is absolutely the correct visa given what you've described, but there's a lot of uncertainty around the boundary between legitimate business visitor and unauthorized foreign worker, so it's definitely wise to proceed with care.

Comment: @phoog I'm not going to visit for extended periods of time. A few days maximum.

Comment: @user626528 that shouldn't make much of a difference except of course for the fact that an immigration officer will look more closely at someone who says they're staying for a longer time even if the person seems credible (if the officer doesn't think you're credible then it doesn't much matter what you say about how long you plan to stay.)  If it's a short visit then the scrutiny around illegal working would probably be less, which would probably be significant if you own a company there.

Comment: @phoog ok thanks, will take this into account.